# MIPS random numbers not outputting to console

Tags: assembly, input, console, mips

I have this MIPS assignment where it generates a random number each time key is pressed with the numbers ranging from 0 to 99. You press Enter key to quit.

However, pressing anything on the keyboard does not output a number on the console. In fact, it does not output anything.  Does anyone know why?

```
.data           # Data declaration section
nl: .asciiz "\n"
msg:    .asciiz "\nHow Lucky Can You Get?"
bye:    .asciiz "\n** Come Back Again **"
    .text
main:
    li  $a3, 0xffff0000  # Base address of I/O
    li  $s1, 2
    sw  $s1, 0($a3) # Enable Keyboard Interrupt
    li  $s1, 0x0000ffff     # Mask to enable all interrupts
    mtc0    $s1, $12        # Store enable bits in Status register
    li  $v0, 4      # Print message
    la  $a0, msg 
    syscall 
    li  $t0, 211        # Seed values
    li  $t1, 3021377 
clear:
    li  $v1, 0      # Clear the flag
ranloop:
    mult    $t0, $t1
    mflo    $t0
    addiu   $t0, $t0, 5923
    beqz    $v1, ranloop    # Keystroke will change $v1
                # to ASCII value for the key
    addiu   $v1, $v1, -10
    beqz    $v1, quit       # Quit if Enter Key
    li  $v0, 4      # Print newline
    la  $a0, nl 
    syscall 
    li  $v1, 100        # Controls Range (0 – 99)
    divu    $t0, $v1
    mfhi    $a0     # Get Remainder
    li  $v0, 1      
    syscall         
    b   clear
quit:
    li  $v0, 4      # Print newline
    la  $a0, bye
    syscall 
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a call to print out the value of `$v1` before the beqz, like so:

```
li      $v0, 1      #print value of $v1
move    $a0, $v1
syscall
beqz    $v1, ranloop    # Keystroke will change $v1
```

It is always 0, no matter how many key presses I do before that code runs. I suspect that the keyboard interrupt is not coming through like you would expect. Take a look at that part of it.

In case you haven't tried it yet, MARS is a nice tool for working in MIPS. It has some useful debugging tools (step through code, view registers and memory, and so forth). Take a look at it [here.](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/)